# How aluminium ring move if DC is suddenly cut?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

The jumping ring experiment is an outstanding demonstration of Faraday's laws of electromagnetic induction and also of Lenz's law. A conducting non-magnetic ring is placed over the extended vertical core of a solenoid. When ac power is applied to the solenoid, the ring is thrown off or held in a state of levitation. This phenomenon happens because the induced current in the ring flows in the direction to counter that of the solenoid current. Consequently, two magnetic fields repel each other, giving rise to the jump effect.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pl7KyVIJ1iE

In this video, the circuit is closed and then open at once.
If it is closed, let the ring fall down and come to rest.  Then open the circuit, what will happen?

Most of the experiments demonstrated by AC, some will use DC, but they only show the result when the switch is closed, that is, jump up and fall down at once. I want to ask what happens to the ring at the moment when the circuit is opened?

Comment: Too much missing information. What ring and what DC circuit (not everyone is familiar with this experiment)? What makes you think anything at all would happen given there is no current the circuit? Please describe the experimental setup and ask a clear question.

Comment: oh, thank you for your comment.

Comment: No problems and thanks for editing.